# how to run mysqli server on appserv 2.5.10?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying use mysqli functions but I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::num_rows() in C:\AppServ\www\edu\files\header.php on line 19
```

I tried to go to `php.ini` and remove `;` from `extension=php_mysqli.dll`
I found it already removed

I tried to restart appachi;
the connection file:

```
// db username
define("USERNAME","root");

// db password
define("PASSWORD","root");

// db servername
define("SERVERNAME","localhost");

// db name
define("NAME","edu");

//connect to db
$mysqli = new mysqli(SERVERNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,NAME);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo $cannot_connect;
}

//select db encoding
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

calling function in a file:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT VALUE FROM SITE_CONFIG WHERE CONF='KEYWORDS'");
if (!$sql) {
    echo "Failed to run query: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
if($mysqli->num_rows($sql) > 0){
    while($rs = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        $keyw = $rs['VALUE'];
    }
}else{
        $keyw = $no_data;
}
```

note : I included connection.php

Comment: @DaHaKa --> I selected it but I still have this: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::num_rows() in C:\AppServ\www\edu\files\header.php on line 19`

Comment: I see, you edited script and because deleted previous comment !

Comment: In `phpinfo()` is `mysqli` extension enabled ?

Comment: i do not know but this the information http://upload.traidnt.net/upfiles/bqr88003.png

Comment: When you add here db name in connection , have you tried it to your server too , or just made mistake during posting question here (when missing db name) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT VALUE FROM SITE_CONFIG WHERE CONF='KEYWORDS'");
if (!$sql) {
    echo "Failed to run query: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
} else {
    if($sql->num_rows > 0){// here must be $sql , not $mysqli
        while($rs = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $rs['VALUE'];
        }
    } else{
            echo "No data";
    }
}
```